# pythonic way to break a dict which value is a list to several dict

Tags: python, dictionary

#### description

- I need to break a dict which value is a list to several dict, keep the other parts.
- The key I want to break may have different name,but the `cond` only and always get one value which type is `list`.

#### example

- input

```
cond = {"type":"image","questionType":["3","4","5"]}

cond = {"type":"example","fieldToBreak":["1","2","3"],"fieldInt":1,"fieldFloat":0.1}
```

- output

```
[
    {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '3'}, 
    {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '4'}, 
    {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '5'}
]

[
    {'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '1', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1},
    {'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '2', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1},
    {'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '3', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1}
]
```

#### what I have tried

```
cond_queue = []
for k,v in cond.items():
    if isinstance(v,list):
        for ele in v:
            cond_copy = cond.copy()
            cond_copy[k] = ele
            cond_queue.append(cond_copy)
        break
```

- It works, but I think it is not the best pythonic solution.

#### question:

- Any better pythonic solution?

Comment: If you got a variable amount of keys that might have instances of type list (as your code suggest) this is probably the best you get. If there is a fixed amount, you can "simplify" it to a dict-comprehension (to get less lines of code but more complex python). You could create something recursive but that's not much clearer then what you got.

Comment: Do you have only one list in the dictionary? Or can you have more than one, like `{"type":"image","questionType":["3","4","5"], "somethingElse":["9","10","11"]}` ? And if so, how should the output look like in this case?

Comment: @alec_djinn didn’t have multiple list in dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible approach utilizing python's built-in functions and standard library. The code should work with any number of keys. It creates all combinations of values' elements in case of multiple lists presented in the original dict. Not sure if this logic a correct one.

```
import itertools

def dict_to_inflated_list(d):

    ans, keys, vals = list(), list(), list()

    # copy keys and 'listified' values in the same order
    for k, v in d.items():
        keys.append(k)
        vals.append(v if isinstance(v, list) else [v])

    # iterate over all possible combinations of elements of all 'listified' values
    for combination in itertools.product(*vals):
        ans.append({k: v for k, v in zip(keys, combination)})

    return ans

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cond = {'type': 'image', 'questionType': ['3', '4', '5']}
    print(dict_to_inflated_list(cond))

    cond = {'a': 0, 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [10, 20]}
    print(dict_to_inflated_list(cond))
```

Output:

```
[{'type': 'image', 'questionType': '3'}, {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '4'}, {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '5'}]
[{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 10}, {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 20}, {'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 10}, {'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 20}]
```

Answer (score 2):

something like the below (the solution is based on the input from the post which I assume represents the general case)

```
cond = {"type": "image", "questionType": ["3", "4", "5"]}
data = [{"type": "image", "questionType": e} for e in cond['questionType']]
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'type': 'image', 'questionType': '3'}, {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '4'}, {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '5'}]
```

Comment: nice one, but the question has an example with only 1  list-attribute, but the code in the question suggests more then 1 (using instance of, iterating the source dict etc).

Comment: @PatrickArtner - this is why I have added the comment "the solution is based on the input from the post which I assume represents the general case" - we need the OP input to understand the use case.

Comment: I add some details, the key may not name `questionType`. Also the name of `key` as argument may be inconvenient when I use this solution, so I want to type check it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
lens = 0
for index, item in enumerate(cond):
    if isinstance(cond[item], list):
        lens = len(cond[item])
        idx = index
        break
print([{k : v if i!=idx else v[j] for i,(k,v) in enumerate(cond.items()) } for j in range(lens)])
```

output:

```
# cond = {"type":"image","questionType":["3","4","5"]}
[{'type': 'image', 'questionType': '3'},
 {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '4'},
 {'type': 'image', 'questionType': '5'}]

# cond = {"type":"example","fieldToBreak":["1","2","3"],"fieldInt":1,"fieldFloat":0.1}
[{'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '1', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1},
 {'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '2', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1},
 {'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '3', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1}]
```

if dict have another shape:

```
# cond = {"questionType":["3","4","5"], "type":"image"}
[{'questionType': '3', 'type': 'image'},
 {'questionType': '4', 'type': 'image'},
 {'questionType': '5', 'type': 'image'}]
```

Comment: Indeed, this is a good answer. Maybe you can give some insight instead of simply posting the code?

Comment: @alec_djinn, what do you mean? what do you need to add?

Comment: For me, the answer is pretty clear like this but I guess someone may have downvoted because you posted a code without any explanation. So my suggestion is to add a little description of the code you have posted so the OP and others can follow your reasoning.

Comment: @alec_djinn, thanks `bro` I remember your advice.

Comment: sorry I'm using python 3.7.7, I try your code but it didn't work, I fix some bugs in it to make it work.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori, thanks dude, if you can share your changes to edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

This little function does the job without any extra argument except the input dictionary

```
def unpack_dict(d):
    n = [len(v) for k,v in d.items() if type(v) is list][0] #number of items in the list
    r = []
    for i in range(n):
        _d = {}
        for k,v in d.items():
            if type(v) is list:
                _d[k] = v[i]
            else:
                _d[k] = v
        r.append(_d)
    return r
    
    


cond = {"type":"example","fieldToBreak":["1","2","3"],"fieldInt":1,"fieldFloat":0.1}

unpack_dict(cond)

[{'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '1', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1},
 {'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '2', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1},
 {'type': 'example', 'fieldToBreak': '3', 'fieldInt': 1, 'fieldFloat': 0.1}]
```

The function determines how many items (`n`) there are in the list entry and uses that info to extract the right value to be inserted in the dictionary. Looping over `n` (`for i in range(n):`) is used to append the correct number of dictionaries in the final output. That's it. Quite simple to read and understand.

Comment: sorry I think my code may be better to read and understand with less temp variable and less control flow. +1 for your effort.